# update rawQuery in to database is not working on android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite, updates

In my project i'm updating the searchtag in the database by using this query

```
      public void updatesearchtag(){
        SQLiteDBHelper sqLiteDBHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        Cursor crs=sqLiteDBHelper.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("update shoply_coupon set searchTag=(Select SearchTag from shoply_retailer_master where retailerId=shoply_coupon.retailerID)",null);
//Cursor crs=sqLiteDBHelper.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("update shoply_coupon set searchTag=(Select SearchTag from shoply_retailer_master where retailerId=shoply_coupon.retailerID)");
}
```

but the query is not working may i know what error i'm doing over here

Comment: i'm not getting any error in log

Answer (score 2):

Use `execSQL()` and not `rawQuery()` for SQL like this.

`rawQuery()` just compiles the SQL but doesn't run it. It is only run when the cursor is moved. `execSQL()` both compiles and runs the SQL.

Also, use `getWritableDatabase()` and not `getReadableDatabase()` for updates.

Comment: public void updatesearchtag(){
        SQLiteDBHelper sqLiteDBHelper = new SQLiteDBHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        Cursor crs=sqLiteDBHelper.getReadableDatabase().execSQL("update shoply_coupon set searchTag=(Select SearchTag from shoply_retailer_master where retailerId=shoply_coupon.retailerID)",null);
    } it showing error plz help

Comment: ... and what is the error? Please edit the question instead of posting code etc. in comments.

Comment: how to used this execSQL() in my coding

Answer (score 0):

Share your code please which you are using for updating . Also about the SearchTag values.

I will suggest to make the Dbclass seprate in your code and use the functions like this. this is a easy way to do every thing such as update,delete,select etc

```
public boolean Update(String SearchTag , ContentValues values) 
{
    if (db.update(TABLE, values, "SearchTag = '"+YourValue+"'", null) > 0)
    {
    return true ;   
    }
    return false ;
}
```

Comment: Yes you need to use the execSQL it is good in that way as said by the laalto but the process I shared you can use the rawquery as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sqLiteDBHelper.getWritableDatabase()
```

instead

```
sqLiteDBHelper.getReadableDatabase()
```

Since you are trying to write into a database which is in **write prevention mode**.

Comment: i've used the getWritableDatabase() till now data is not there

Comment: did u tried executing the query in sqlite browser? It seems there is some mistake in your query also